# Prevent default action after AJAX response is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, sweetalert

After the AJAX call of GetCurrentTime is made and the response object is returned the new sweet alert that is called only stays for a second as prevent default does not stop the event from running. How do you stop this from executing so that popup stays until it is clicked. The initial event.preventDefault() works as it is on the button click.

```
 function alertYourself(ctl, event) {
        var defaultAction = $(ctl).prop("href");
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: 'SUBMIT DATA',
            input: 'email',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Home.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                        data: '{name: "ITS ALIVE" }',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            swal({
                                title: "Are you sure?",
                                text: response.d,
                                type: "warning",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonText: "Continue",
                                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                                closeOnConfirm: false,
                                closeOnCancel: true
                            },
                             function (isConfirm) {
                                 if (isConfirm) {
                                     window.location.href = defaultAction;
                                     return true;
                                 } else {
                                     return false;
                                 }
                             });
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            this.event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using 2 popups in a row? I'm not sure why you have the 2nd and 3rd event.preventDefault() - once you call that function, the default has already been prevented. Plus it's useless to call it after the AJAX response because the outer function has already returned.

I've never used that sweet alert before, but it could have to do with the fact that you already have an alert box open and you are trying to open another one. You might have to programatically close the first alert before opening a new one - you may even need to set a timeout of, say 100ms, before opening the new one.